# Responding to on_adaptive_card_invoke

Tags: python, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm struggling to respond to an action sent by an Adapative card with a Teams bot. The action is being sent like this:

```
"actions": [
  {
    "type": "Action.Execute",
    "title": "Approve",
    "verb": "APPROVE",
    "data": {
            "USER_ID": 13
          }
  },
]
```

This is being handled by the on_adapative_card_invoke method in our bot:

```
async def on_adaptive_card_invoke(self, turn_context: TurnContext, invoke_value: AdaptiveCardInvokeValue) -> AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse:
    return AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse(status_code=200)
```

However Teams always shows 'Something went wrong. Please try again'

How should the bot respond, is it with another post or an actual returned response. I've tried both with no luck and there are no samples for this method in Python.

TIA

Comment: Please have look into this-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-request-approval
Currently this sample is available in Nodejs and C#.

Comment: did you get chance to check the above sample?

Answer (score 1):

I'm muddling through this with python as well.

According to Microsoft's Universal Action Model the response [requires a specific format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/universal-action-model#response-format).

If you're not looking to send or replace the card after the card has been invoked you can return an empty message.

```py
return AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse(
  status_code=HTTPStatus.OK,
  type="application/vnd.microsoft.activity.message")
```

In my opinion, to prevent the card from being invoked multiple times, it's best to replace the card once it has been invoked.

```py
return AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse(
  status_code=HTTPStatus.OK,
  type="application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
  value=card
)
```

In my case the card was [json formatted adaptive card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-of-adaptive-card) that I [deserialized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: This might have worked back in 2022, but for me this is no longer working. and I'm getting the "Something went wrong. Please try again" error. Specifically the case when we do not provide a value.